# Make jqgrid only show group footer at last row in group

Tags: jqgrid

Currently I'm using group and pagination in jqgrid. The data is long and each group might cross a few page in jqgid. 
I'm apply the group total and it seems the group total exists at every page and the calculate (sum) base on the existing row at current page. In my use case it is misleading, I wish to show group total after last row of each group.

Is it achievable? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us a jqGrid code? Please, specify which version of jqGrid is used (Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= version 4.7)?

Comment: due to i can't amend title, so i create new topic:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138008/make-jqgrid-only-show-single-group-footer-at-last-row-in-group)