# Make jqgrid only show single group footer at last row in group

Tags: jqgrid

Currently I'm using group and pagination in jqgrid. The data is long and each group might cross a few page in jqgid. I'm apply the group total and it seems the group total exists at every page and the calculate (sum) base on the existing row at current page. In my use case it is misleading, I wish to show group total after last row of each group.
I'm using version v5.1.1 (Guriddo jqGrid JS)
Is it achievable?

```
$grid.jqGrid({

            data: dataarray,
            datatype: 'local',
            height: 'auto',
            width: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortable: true,
            loadonce: true,
            colNames: columnarray,
            colModel: columnmodelarray,
            rownumbers: true,
            grouping: true, 

            rowNum: 20,
            gridview: true, 
            regional : 'en',
            autowidth:true, 
            shrinkToFit:false,
            rowList: [20, 50, 100, 200,400,999999999999],           
            userDataOnFooter: true,
            footerrow:true,
            sortname:sortname,
            sortorder:sortorder,
            colMenu : true,

            pager: pagerid,
            groupingView:groupviewjsondata,
            loadComplete:function()
            {
                //calculate total to put at bottom
                var columncontent={};
                var i=0;
                var lastcolumn='';

                var isshownumber=0;

                $.each(colmodels,function(colno,colobj)
                {
                    if(colobj.datatype=='number' && colobj.withtotal == true)
                    {
                        var tmptotal=0;
                        $.each(rp.result.data,function(row_id,row)
                        {
                            if(typeof row[ colobj['name']] =='string')
                            {
                                row[ colobj['name']]=parseFloat(row[ colobj['name']]);
                            }

                            tmptotal += row[ colobj['name']];
                        });
                        columncontent[colobj['name']]=tmptotal;
                        isshownumber++;

                    }
                    if( isshownumber==1) 
                    {                       
                        columncontent[lastcolumn]='<div style="text-align:right">'+lang('Total')+'</div>';                      
                    }
                    if((colobj.datatype=='date' || colobj.datatype=='string')&& (colobj.hidden===undefined ||colobj.hidden==false) )
                    {
                        lastcolumn=colobj['name'];  
                    }

                });

                $grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',columncontent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please post the groupingView and colModel settings? As can be seen from [this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary/index.html)  the sum of the group is not per page (as you state), but for the whole group.

Comment: Here is sample:
`defaultgroupview= {
     groupField: ["accounts"],
     groupColumnShow: [false],
     groupText: ["<b>Account Code - Name: {0}</b>"],
     groupOrder: ["asc"],
     groupSummary:[true],
    }`

Comment: short code of column model:
`[{"name":"document_date","index":"document_date","datatype":"date","width":80,"colmenu":true,"coloptions":{},"sorttype":"date","formatter":"date","formatoptions":{"srcformat":"ISO8601Long","newformat":"d-m-Y"},"title":"Doc. Date"},
{"name":"bpartners","index":"bpartners","datatype":"string","width":100,"colmenu":true,"coloptions":{},"sorttype":"text","align":"left","title":"Business Partner"},
{"name":"document_no","index":"document_no","datatype":"string","width":100,"colmenu":true,"coloptions":{},"sorttype":"text","align":"left","title":"Doc. No."},.....];`

Comment: As far as I understand correct the requirement this is not supported automatically from the script. When you see the demo from my previous post, you will see that using the last version, the sum is per group and not per page. We will try to realize this feature, since I think it have seance. I will let you know in the next days about the status

Comment: thanks tony, cause there is minimal thousand of rows, and i need to allow user customize the column when needed, without pagination the browser will freeze.

Comment: Just a note - you can place the sums of the header overcoming this requirement. To do so set  groupSummaryPos to header in groupingView. See [docs for more](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#options)

Comment: Hi, yes after change to top I can see the group total at header, however the total seems offset 1 column. Example I have header 'Date, Doc No, Cheque no, Debit Amt, Credit Amt', Now the 'Debit Group Total' appear at column 'Cheque No, 'Credit Group Total' appear at column 'Debit Amt'.

Comment: I'm notice some situation group total ok, and some situation it offset. I will troubleshoot some more. Anyhow, there is bar appear at every page which is sum by page.

Comment: I recommend you to use the latest version 5.2.1 and if possible post a full jqGrid setup with sample data.

Comment: seems latest version the group total at header it still sum by page. At the mean time my work around is dump grid data into textarea, draw new table in new window when use wish to see accurate total. I'm look forward new release of this use case. So far I'm happy with JQ grid since I'm bought, however my use case and sample data is dynamic, it break into many function & files. The columns model, setting & calculation, is self generated. the table and json consist of 100 columns and thousand of rows. Sorry of can't supply simplified grid.

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html) - the total is not per page, but per group see the group value AROUT. The only that I can think is that you provide the data dynamivcally per page and not at once - in this case it is as you describe

Comment: strange, we load data once only. I will try to research according the sample. thanks. Anything i will update here.

Comment: i still can't fix this issue. by the way i you can post the demo as answer. i will troubleshoot my data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html) - the total is not per page, but per group see the group value AROUT. The only that I can think is that you provide the data dynamically per page (from server with paging) and not at once - in this case it is as you describe